# AWS codebuild is not gaining access to repos even after allowing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

So I'm trying give codebuild access to my GitHub repositories & once signing in, and clicking `authorise`, codebuild still won't display the repositories from my account and organisations?

I've gone into my GitHub **settings/oauth_application_policy** and I've noticed that there is no `AWS codebuild` approved application?! Even after authorising it, nothing will show.

The reason I need to create a `codebuild` project through the actual `codebuild` page, is because when creating it through the `codepipeline` page, I cannot edit or add artifacts to the created `codebuild` project! I need to be able add an Artifact location or else one `action` in my `codepipeline` will fail.

Is this  a known error?

Answer (score 3):

The answer was that you need to head into your oauth settings on GitHub and specify which organisations are available by the oAUth application! In my case I needed to setup codebuild for an organisation repo.